# Validation message not showing on input type

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't get a validation message to show on an input type. I'm using for validator.pattern with Form Group and not sure why it will not show. The mat-error tag will not show for anything over two decimal places. I'm looking for help with a possible solution to this. If someone could help me with this I would appreciate.

html

```
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" floatLabel="always">
          <mat-label>Breakfast</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" class="example-right-align" placeholder="0" 
      formControlName="bfastAmount" />
          <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['bfastAmount'].errors?.pattern" class="text- 
      danger">Please provide a valid amount.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

ts

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
bfastAmount: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('^\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2}$')]),
 });
```

Comment: That totally should work. Try to isolate the problem by testing `mat-error` without `*ngIf`, then with a simple validator

Comment: What would be a simple validator? An example of one.

Comment: <mat-error class="text- danger">Please provide a valid amount.</mat-error>. First check above. If it works then a simple pattern could be like Validators.pattern([0-9]*). it will just accept numbers.